# Multiple contracts in a single transaction

Tags: kotlin, corda

I've a requirement where there is an input State (State A & Contract A) and an output State (State B & Contract B). Can we incorporate this in a single transaction?
Also, how is the verify method of the 2 different contracts invoked? It'd be very helpful if an example is shared with the response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and both contracts are invoked over the whole transaction. Effectively, the node runs:

```
ContractA().verify(transaction)
ContractB().verify(transaction)
```

You must therefore take care when writing the two `verify` methods. Often, you'll want to write each contract's `verify` method so that it only looks at the commands and states related to that contract. For example:

```
class ExampleContract : Contract {
    companion object {
        val ID = "com.example.ExampleContract"
    }

    interface ExampleCommands : CommandData {
        class Issue : ExampleCommands
        class Transfer : ExampleCommands
        class Exit: ExampleCommands
    }

    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val exampleCommands = tx.commandsOfType<ExampleCommands>()
        val exampleInputs = tx.inputsOfType<ExampleState>()
        val exampleOutputs = tx.outputsOfType<ExampleState>()

        exampleCommands.forEach { command ->
            when (command.value) {
                is ExampleCommands.Issue -> {
                    if (exampleInputs.isNotEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("Issuance should have no inputs.")
                    if (exampleOutputs.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("Issuance should have outputs.")
                    // TODO: More verification.
                }

                is ExampleCommands.Transfer -> {
                    if (exampleInputs.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("Transfer should have inputs.")
                    if (exampleOutputs.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("Transfer should have outputs.")
                    // TODO: More verification.
                }

                is ExampleCommands.Exit -> {
                    if (exampleInputs.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("Exit should have inputs.")
                    if (exampleOutputs.isNotEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("Exit should have no outputs.")
                    // TODO: More verification.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This helps a lot.